# How to get DataTable Column Names when exporting data to CSV?

Tags: c#, datatable, streamwriter

I have the following code that works for exporting large amounts of data from a DataTable to a CSV. For some reason, the columns of the DataTable are not being exporting along with the rows.

Am I missing something in the following code? Does the DataTable columns not automatically get exported when getting the Rows?

```
 private void ExportToCSV()
    {
        try
        {
            string delimiter = ",";
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dgvSearchFilter.Columns)
            {
                dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(col.Name, typeof(string)));
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < dgvSearchFilter.RowCount; i++)
            {
                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                for (int j = 0; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    dr[j] = dgvSearchFilter.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value;
                }
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            }

            string unique = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssffff");
            string fileName = "SQLQueryOutput_" + unique + ".csv";
            using (StreamWriter swr = new StreamWriter(File.Open(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), fileName), FileMode.CreateNew), Encoding.Default, 1000000))
            { 
                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                {
                    swr.WriteLine(string.Join(delimiter, dr.ItemArray));
                }
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Your file was generated and its ready for use.");
}
```

Comment: CSV is  just text. If you want column headers, you'll need to output that as a row with writeline before you write your data rows.

Comment: Also, as an aside, CSV, being just text, needs special handling of commas and other special data (such as single quotes) that programs like Excel might interpret as dates or whatnot. You're not pushing metadata here so anything opening it will try to guess data types.

Comment: So do I loop through my columns, and convert them into a DataRow?

Comment: I tried looping through the columns and writing them before the DataRows with  `swr.Write(string.Join(delimiter, dataTable.ColumnName));` But that didn't add the columns in separate cells

Comment: CSV doesn't have cells. Check your output in a text editor before trying to open it in Excel. You might notice something interesting.

Comment: swr.Write(string.Join(delimiter, dataTable.ColumnName)); implies that you are joining a single column name to ... nothing ... pop it into a string builder or list<string> in the top where you're already looping. Save some trouble.

Comment: Can you please provide some code sample for that and how it'll integrate with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void ExportToCSV()
{
    string delimiter = ",";

    var columns = dgSearchFilter.Columns.Select(c => c.Name.Cointains(deliminter)?"\"" + c.Name + "\"": c.Name);
    string header = string.Join(delimiter, columns);

    var unique =  DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssffff");
    using (var swr = new StreamWriter($"SQLQueryOutput_{unique}.csv"))
    {
        swr.WriteLine(header);

        var rows = dgvSearchFilter.Rows.Select(r => r.Cells.Select(c => c.Value.ToString()));
        foreach (var row in rows)
        { 
             var line = row.Select(r => r.Contains(delimiter) || r.Contains("\n")?"\"" + r + "\"":r);
             swr.WriteLine(string.Join(delimiter, line));
        }
    }

    MessageBox.Show("Your file was generated and its ready for use.");
}
```

Comment: Hi. DataGridView in Windows Form does not contain a .Select() method, so `dgvSearchFilter.Columns.Select()` doesn't work.

Comment: @Raza156 I believe it does, though, implement IEnumerable, should still be able to do this if you have a `using System.Linq` at the top of the file.

Comment: Hi. I tried but couldn't find the .Select() for DataGridView. Maybe it used to be there in previous versions? I did use your answer and integrated it within my answer (posted below). It seems to work pretty efficiently. Thanks! Let me know if you find something in the answer I posted to be incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this.

```
    private void ExportToCSV()
    {
        List<string> headers = new List<string>();
        try
        {
            string delimiter = ",";
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dgvSearchFilter.Columns)
            {
                dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(col.Name, typeof(string)));
                headers.Add(col.Name);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < dgvSearchFilter.RowCount; i++)
            {
                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                for (int j = 0; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    dr[j] = dgvSearchFilter.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value;
                }
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            }

            string unique = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssffff");
            string fileName = "SQLQueryOutput_" + unique + ".csv";
            using (StreamWriter swr = new StreamWriter(File.Open(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), fileName), FileMode.CreateNew), Encoding.Default, 1000000))
            { 
                swr.WriteLine(string.Join(delimiter, headers));
                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                {
                    swr.WriteLine(string.Join(delimiter, dr.ItemArray));
                }
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Your file was generated and its ready for use.");
}
```

Comment: I didn't test this, so I apologize if there's a syntax error or something, but you get the idea. Add your headers to a List and just pop them in the output before you write your data.

Comment: Thank you. I came across another issue that you just pointed out. Some columns with no values in the table, are now having values. Basically, some other column's value is being written in them. I tried adding `if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dgvSearchFilter.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString()))
                        {
                            dr[j] = "";
                        }
                        else 
                        {
                            dr[j] = dgvSearchFilter.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
                        }` 
But that didn't do the trick. Any ideas?

Comment: Well, you're using ItemArray which is probably why. It will have a variable number of columns, I assume (though I don't KNOW, I don't have this fired up in IDE at the moment). There's actually a lot of interesting problems with CSV exports and most folks end up using a little library (3rd party or custom) for it

Comment: Also, a debugger and stepping though this as it exports is ideal to see what's going on with your values and what's being written and why. I can't help a lot more since I don't have your data and whatnot to do that with.

Comment: @Raza156 The most likely explanation here is you have data with commas as part of the data. You need to account for that as part of your export.

Answer (score 0):

so I modified my code as per @Joel Coehoorn's comment. I was able to export 1,000,000 rows of data in less than/about a minute (at least a 230 MB file)

The code looks like the following:

```
            var headers = dgvSearchFilter.Columns.Cast<DataGridViewColumn>();
            string delimiter = ",";
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dgvSearchFilter.Columns)
            {
                dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(col.Name, typeof(string)));
            }

            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvSearchFilter.Rows)
            {
                DataRow dataRow = dt.NewRow();
                foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
                {
                    if (row.Cells[cell.ColumnIndex].Value == null || row.Cells[cell.ColumnIndex].Value == DBNull.Value || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(row.Cells[cell.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString()))
                    {
                        dataRow[cell.ColumnIndex] = " ";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dataRow[cell.ColumnIndex] = cell.Value.ToString();
                    }
                }
                dt.Rows.Add(dataRow);
            }

            string unique = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssffff");
            string fileName = "SQLQueryOutput_" + unique + ".csv";
            using (StreamWriter swr = new StreamWriter(File.Open(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), fileName), FileMode.CreateNew), Encoding.Default, 1000000))
            {
                swr.WriteLine(string.Join(",", headers.Select(column => "\"" + column.HeaderText + "\"").ToArray()));
                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                {
                    var line = dr.ItemArray.Select(r => r.ToString().Contains(delimiter) || r.ToString().Contains("\n") ? "\"" + r + "\"" : r);
                    swr.WriteLine(string.Join(delimiter, line));
                }
            }

            MessageBox.Show("Your file was generated and its ready for use.");
```